# How to set focus to the next edittext after maxlength in current edittext is reached?

Tags: android, textwatcher

I am using a custom keyboard.

I have 4 `EditText` with one `Button`.

Condition:-

The max length of `EditText` is 1. Whenever a value is entered in the `editText`, the focus should move to next `EditText`. I am implementing this using `TextWatcher`.

The problem is when I entered any value in EditText ,the focus or cursor goes to next EditText, which is fine, but if the user wants to edit the entered value he is not able to have focus on touched `EditText` because the max value is already there. And obviously the cursor moves to the next EditText.

code:-

```
public class Listener implements TextWatcher {

        EditText editText;
        public Listener(EditText et)
        {
            editText = et;
        }
        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s)
        {
            int id = editText.getId();
            String str = s.toString();
            if(!str.isEmpty())
            {
                switch (id) {
                case R.id.edit_txt1:
                    et2.requestFocus();
                    break;
                case R.id.edit_txt3:
                    et3.requestFocus();
                    break;
                case R.id.edit_txt3:
                    et4.requestFocus();
                    break;
                case R.id.edit_pin4:
                    createPin4.clearFocus();

                    EditText txt =(EditText)findViewById(R.id.foc);
                    txt.requestFocus();
                    break;
                }
            }
            else
            {
                editText.setFocusable(true);
            }

        }

        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count,
                int after) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {


        }

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Have `Listener` implement the `OnClickListener`, and do the following:

```
public void onClick(View v){
  this.requestFocus();
}
```

Also, override the `beforeTextChanged()` to empty the text field.

I'm pretty sure the onClick event would be fired before the TextWatcher, but the only way to know for sure is to try it.